# Broken mouse double-click button on new distros

Tags: mouse, doubleclick

I have an A4tech F5 mouse. It has a double-click button, and it worked well earlier, but now it does not work on new distros. This acts like a single left-click.
I have tested some distros, and double-click button:

**works** on:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Ubuntu 20.10

xev output:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 49, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
    root 0x538, subw 0x0, time 56306, (163,33), root:(709,475),
    state 0x0, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 49, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
    root 0x538, subw 0x0, time 56331, (163,33), root:(709,475),
    state 0x100, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonPress event, serial 49, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
    root 0x538, subw 0x0, time 56342, (163,33), root:(709,475),
    state 0x0, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 49, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
    root 0x538, subw 0x0, time 56367, (163,33), root:(709,475),
    state 0x100, button 1, same_screen YES
```

**does not work** on:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Fedora 36 + gnome (x11)
- Fedora 36 + gnome (wayland)
- Fedora 36 + kde
- Pop OS 22.04

xev output:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x600001,
    root 0x770, subw 0x0, time 121673, (167,90), root:(3085,641),
    state 0x10, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x600001,
    root 0x770, subw 0x0, time 121749, (167,90), root:(3085,641),
    state 0x110, button 1, same_screen YES
```

Problem definetely in Linux, because i have MacOS (Hackintosh) and FydeOS (fork of ChromeOS) on the same computer and my mouse works perfectly on those systems.

I already tried to change the settings in "Accessibility - Pointing & clicking" for gnome, no luck.
Maybe, i should downgrade some packages? I do not need wayland.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Much of your detail is off-topic, but you gave no clues as to the 20.04 you used; was it the GA or HWE kernel stack & which?  20.04.5 using HWE is using 5.15 or the kernel of 22.04 which is useful detail; but you only specifically mention 5.8 mention c/of 20.10 detail; given no clues as to what 20.04 stack worked for you*

Comment: To not have your question removed as off topic remove all references to other OS then Ubuntu as they are off topic.